# upload files only after submit

Tags: php, jquery, dropzone.js

I'm trying to use dropzonejs in order to upload multiple files.

I want to upload them only when i submit the form (post the page)

how can i do that?

```
<?PHP
if ($_POST)
    print_r($_FILES);
?>
```

here is my form:

```
<form method='post' action='index.php' enctype='multipart/form-data'>

        <input type='text' name='title'  value="" class="form-control" />
        <textarea name="msgText" class="form-control" ></textarea>

            <label class="control-label col-sm-1">Attached File:</label>
            <div class="dropzone"></div>

            <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-success form-control">           
    </form>
```

Comment: http://www.dropzonejs.com/#enqueuing-file-uploads

Comment: Show your js code of dropzone

Answer (score 0):

Add name attribute to submit imput 
   `<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="button" class="btn btn-success form-control">`

Then in PHP:

`if(isset($_POST['button'])){
        ...some code...
    }`

Comment: how will it help me o post the files?